# How to fetch two associated Database values Using Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hi I have two tables in DB.The first table is given below.

> Table name-

t_hcsy_details

> class name in model-

```
class THcsyDetails < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

The values in side table is given below.

```
HCSY_Details_ID  HCSY_ID  HCSY_Fund_Type_ID   Amount
1                 2        1                   1125
2                 2        2                    390
3                 2        3                     285
4                 2        4                   100
5                 2        5                      60
6                 2        6                      40
```

My second table is given below.

> Table Name:

t_hcsy_fund_type_master

> class in model:

```
class THcsyFundTypeMaster < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Table values are given below.

```
 HCSY_Fund_Type_ID   Fund_Type_Code  Fund_Type_Name   Amount

        1                   1               woods         1125

        2                   2               Burning       390

        3                   3               goods         285

        4                   4               brahmin       100

        5                   5               swd           60

        6                   6               Photo          40
```

I know only HCSY_ID value(i.e-2) of first table.But i need Fund_Type_Name and Amount from second table.As you can see one HCSY_ID has 6 different records.But i need all Fund_Type_Name and Amount of one HCSY_ID. Please help me to resolve this issue by creating object for both two classes shown above.Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified any relationships setup, so it would be easier to split this in two queries:

```
# you already have hcsy_id
fund_type_ids = THcsyDetails.where(hcsy_id: hcsy_id).pluck(:hcsy_fund_type_id)
fund_types = THcsyFundTypeMaster.where(id: fund_type_ids)
fund_types.group(:fund_type_name).sum(:amount)
```

In case you had proper relationships setup, the above would've simplified to:

```
THcsyDetails.
joins(association_name). # THcsyFundTypeMaster
where(hcsy_id: hcsy_id).
group("#{t = THcsyFundTypeMaster.table_name}.fund_type_name").
sum("#{t}.amount")
```